# IPhone Not Showing Full Option for HTML select iOS 12.1.4

Tags: html, ios, iphone, responsive-design

I have a web application that is responsive. I simply cannot see the full label for an HTML select on an iPhone. It will say something like "really long str.." Is there a fix out there for this? Androids wrap the selections.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to fix this, as you have not provided me with a snippet of code. Copy the html from your page and edit the question. Otherwise, you can try using css @media rules. Try doing this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>example code</title>
  <style rel="stylesheet">
  p {
      padding: 1%;
      text-align: center;
      border: solid 5px black;
      border-radius: 25px;
      color: white;
      background-color: grey;
      display: inline;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
  <p> Really long line of text that didn't fit in box </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This sample html code will automatically wrap around the

tag and it should work with iPhone. Feel free to edit code to make it responsive.